# Gmail Email Markup not Working

Tags: html, email, gmail, json-ld

I'm testing Gmail's [Email Markup functionality for Parcel Deliveries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery), and it seems I can't get it right. This is the e-mail content after [sending an e-mail to myself](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema):

```
Return-Path: <test.email@gmail.com>
Received: from my-pc.local ([my.ip.add.ress])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id 68sm3737559qgz.8.2015.01.29.06.06.37
        for <test.email@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 29 Jan 2015 06:06:38 -0800 (PST)
Date: Thu, 29 Jan 2015 11:06:33 -0300
From: "Test Name" <test.email@gmail.com>
To: test.email@gmail.com
Subject: Your package is on its way
Message-ID: <20150129140633.GA18059@my-pc.local>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
User-Agent: Mutt/1.5.23 (2014-03-12)

<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "ParcelDelivery",
      "deliveryAddress": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "Test Address",
        "addressLocality": "Test locality",
        "addressRegion": "Test Region",
        "addressCountry": "CL",
        "postalCode": "7551234"
      },
      "expectedArrivalUntil": "2015-02-12T12:00:00-04:00",
      "carrier": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Test org"
      },
      "itemShipped": {
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "iPod Mini"
      },
      "partOfOrder": {
        "@type": "Order",
        "orderNumber": "176057",
        "merchant": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "name": "Test Org 2"
        },
        "orderStatus": "OrderInTransit"
      },
      "trackingUrl": "http://track.com/track/1234567890",
      "trackingNumber": "1234567890"
    }
    </script>
    <p>Test paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The markup is valid according to the [markup validator](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/). There are recommended (but not required) fields that I'm missing. Adding them doesn't help.

I have also tried the microdata format with no luck so far:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ParcelDelivery">
      <div itemprop="deliveryAddress" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="Test Address"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US"/>
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94107"/>
      </div>
      <meta itemprop="expectedArrivalUntil" content="2015-01-12T12:00:00-08:00"/>
      <div itemprop="carrier" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Test Carrier"/>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="itemShipped" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="iPod Mini"/>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="partOfOrder" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
        <meta itemprop="orderNumber" content="176057"/>
        <div itemprop="merchant" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Bob Dole"/>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="orderStatus" content="OrderInTransit"/>
      </div>
      <meta itemprop="trackingUrl" content="http://track.com/track/1234567890"/>
      <meta itemprop="trackingNumber" content="1234567890"/>
    </div>
    <p>Test paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

I'm using mutt to send the e-mail:

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" test.email@gmail.com -s "Your package is on its way" < test.html
```

Or without content type:

```
mutt test.email@gmail.com -s "Your package is on its way" < test.html
```

Comment: I have the same issue, the microdata passes the validator, but even when sending an email to myself they are discarded. I added an SPF record to my DNS yesterday though I don't think it is needed for self testing (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema).

Comment: I eventually managed to do it. I had to add an SPF record and mark google IP 2a00:1450:4010:c07::264 as permitted sender. I guess it's because I use google SMTP relay.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard thanks, I'll definitely try that out.

Comment: Actually, the IP is not always the same and it worked only from time to time. If you use google SMTP relay, your DNS record should look like this : `600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Google SMTP relay, you have to use an SPF record looking like this :

```
600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en

Comment: can you elaborate more? i facing the same problem, pls

Answer (score 1):

The markup looks fine. You need to authenticate your mail with DKIM or SPF though (see https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#email_sender_quality_guidelines). The easiest way to achieve this is to use Gmails SMTP server instead of your own.

Comment: I am using Gmail's SMTP servers, here's an example smtp log: `Jan 29 16:40:13 host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user=test.email@gmail.com from=test.email@gmail.com recipients=test.email@gmail.com mailsize=1447 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 OK 1422560413 50sm7879005qgj.12 - gsmtp' exitcode=EX_OK` . I can't find the DKIM signature in the raw email content, though.

Comment: I assume test.email@gmail.com is not your real address!? Try using your real address.

Comment: I replaced all occurrences of my real address with test.email@gmail.com

Comment: Any news on this bug since January? Because I have exactly the same.

Comment: And now more than 5 years later, and Iʼm facing exactly the same problem, with no solutions. SPF and DKIM are working fine. Markup checks out. Also tried sending via Google SMTP, still nada.