# google-schema email is not recognised

Tags: html, gmail, google-schemas

I tried to test simpel email markup. Markup is validated by tester with some recommendations but without errors. I am using simple script and sending to myself. But, still, markup is not recognised. DKIM and SPF are not needed, but configured and controlled. What I am doing wrong?

Script:

```
function testMarkup() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test').getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    from: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Test' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>dfgdfgdgdgg</title>
       <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "FoodEstablishmentReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "OT12345",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "John Smith"
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "FoodEstablishment",
        "name": "Wagamama",
        "telephone": "044755755755",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "1 Tavistock Street",
          "addressLocality": "London",
          "addressRegion": "Greater London",
          "postalCode": "WC2E 7PG",
          "addressCountry": "United Kingdom"
        }
      },
      "startTime": "2017-04-10T08:00:00+00:00",
      "partySize": "2",
    "reservationStatus": "confirmed",
    "modifiedTime": "2013-11-03T21:00:00+01:00",
    "modifyReservationUrl": "https://example.com/linktomodification"
    }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p>
      This a test for a Restaurant reservation Google Now card in Gmail.
    </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have adjusted scheme and html that validator returns 0 errors and 0 recommendations, SPF is ok; DKIM is ok; but without any results

Comment: kind of similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258309/email-markup-gmail-modifying-the-script-tag-to-add-extra-string-3d

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this issue happens if your HTML is invalid. Try to use again a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

If you use Google SMTP relay, you have to use an SPF record looking like: `600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all"` based from this [support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en).

You may check this related thread: [Gmail Email Markup not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216823/gmail-email-markup-not-working)

Comment: I have adjusted scheme and html that validator returns 0 errors and 0 recommendations, SPF is ok; DKIM is ok; but without any results